# Remove fields with special characters

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I'm trying to remove all fields that have special characters (`@?.*` etc) in their text.

I think I should be using

```
Filter(function(x) {grepl('|[^[:punct:]]).*?', x)} == FALSE, data$V1)
```

where `data$V1` contains my data. However, it seems like

```
grepl('|[^[:punct:]]).*?', x)
```

fails with trivial examples like

```
grepl('|[^[:punct:]]).*?', 'M')
```

which outputs `TRUE` even though `M` has no special characters. How should I be using `grepl` to remove fields with special characters from a column of data?

Comment: Remove the starting `|`?

Comment: `grepl('[^[:alnum:]_]+', c('m','m@','M9*'))` or `grepl('\\W+', c('m','m@','M9*'))` as seen in the regular expression help: "The symbol `\w` matches a ‘word’ character (a synonym for `[[:alnum:]_]`, an extension) and `\W` is its negation `([^[:alnum:]_])`."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for "special characters", you can search for the negation of alphanumeric characters as such:

```
grepl('[^[:alnum:]_]+', c('m','m@','M9*')) 
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

or use the symbol `\W`

```
grepl('\\W+', c('m','m@','M9*')) 
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`\W` is explained in the [regular expression help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html):

> "The symbol \w matches a ‘word’ character (a synonym for `[[:alnum:]_]`, an extension) and \W is its negation (`[^[:alnum:]_]̀`)."

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a regular expression with a `|` make it literally useless since it will match *anything*.

See this JS example:

```js
console.log('With the starting pipe    => ' + /|([\W]).*?/.test('M'));
console.log('Without the starting pipe => ' + /([\W]).*?/.test('M'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put those inside `[...]` and provide this to the pattern argument to `grepl`, then negate.

```
data$V1[!grepl("[@?.*]", data$V1)]
```

For example,

```
> x <- c("M", "3@3", "8.*x")
> x[!grepl("[@?.*]", x)]
[1] "M"
```